# Error unselect fullcalendar when user selected time in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar that I need to filter user can't make the agenda if the time he choose is passed.

If user choose the right time, the popup will show, and when user choose the time has passed, the popup will not show.

I tried using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect'); return false;`, but it's effect on all the day after today. Do you know where's the error on my code ?

Here's the code

```
console.log(view.name);
var enddate2 = moment(end).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var startdate = moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var starttime = moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
var timenow = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
var endtime = moment(end).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
var enddate = moment(end).subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var starts = moment(start).format('HH:mm');
var ends = moment(end).format('HH:mm');
console.log(starttime);
console.log(timenow);
if (view.name == 'month') {
  $('#myAgenda #startdate').val(startdate);
  $('#myAgenda #enddate').val(enddate);
  $('#myAgenda #startsat').val(starts);
  $('#myAgenda #endsat').val(ends);
} else if (view.name == 'agendaDay') {
  if (starttime > timenow) {
    $('#myAgenda #startdate').val(startdate);
    $('#myAgenda #enddate').val(enddate2);
    $('#myAgenda #startsat').val(starts);
    $('#myAgenda #endsat').val(ends);
  } else if (starttime < timenow) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: starttime and timenow are STRINGS - you don't want to compare "DD-MM-YYYY" etc e.g. "21-01-2020" will be less than "31-03-1908" - clearly it isn't

Comment: so I need t convert or what ?

Comment: don't use `.format` except where you need to display it ... e.g. for this code as shown `var starttime = moment(start)` and `ar timenow = moment()`

Comment: I have trid deleted `.format` but it still didn't work. So how I compare the starttime and timenow  ?

Comment: @IkramShabri momentJS has its own comparison functions - check the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/